# Drop down menu not populating, where is my error?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, dropdown

So, I have struggled for 2 days to understand what my error is. My drop down list is not populating with data from the database. I am using Java EE and MySQL.

I can insert data in the database without a problem but when i retrieve it for some reason the jsp doesn't do its thing correctly so that I always get the drop down empty.
This is the table I am using:

```
create table category(
    category_id int auto_increment,
    name varchar(30),
        primary key(category_id)
        );
```

This is the servlet I am using and the method for executing the query. As you can see I am returning a List of objects and then I am adding it as a request attribute in the doGet method. So I guess until here everything should work fine.

```
public class DropDownServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
        try {
            List<Category> categories = retrieveCategories();
            request.setAttribute("categories", categories);
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("viewdropdown.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<Category> retrieveCategories() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.initializeConnection();
        String query = "Select * from category";
        PreparedStatement pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();


        ResultSet rs = pstmnt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

            int id = rs.getInt("category_id");
            String name = rs.getString("name");

            Category cat = new Category(id,name);
            categories.add(cat);

        }

        conn.close();
        return categories;
    }
```

and here is the jsp with the dropdown which doesn't display the data that it should.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Dropdown page</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>The names of the categories are the following:</h1>

<select id ="dropdown">
    <c:forEach items="${categories}" var="category">
        <option value = "${category.name}">${category.name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
    <br>
    <br>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
So I have created this hardcoded test method to test my code and I add it as request parameter identically to how I added the other method with the DB query. My DropDown is still empty, so the problem could be from the way I try to display the items in the jsp. I think it could be in the loop I have.

```
public static List<Category> testMethod(){
        List<Category> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Category one = new Category(1,"Blue");
        Category two = new Category(2,"Red");
        list.add(one);
        list.add(two);

        return list;

    }
```

Comment: First determine where your problem is. Can you show data in your dropdown by hard coding it in `retrieveCategories()`? If so, then your problem is in getting the data from the database, otherwise it's in passing the data to the JSP. If you look at your code and "guess" that everything is fine, you'll never get anywhere, you need to actually try and test your code.

Comment: ok thank you,  i will do that and i will let you know

Comment: ok, so i hardcoded the Objects and added them as request.I have added the edited modifications in the original post.It is still empty , so it could be from the way i display the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `${categories}` is an empty collection.

First, make sure, you have imported the JSTL Core library into your JSP page. This is done by putting

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

at the top of the JSP page.

Additionally, you can check on the JSP side if the collection is empty by adding somewhere:

`<c:out value="${categories.size()}" />`.

Also, you are using Expression Language directly between the HTML `<option>` tags, so you will also need adding:

`<%@ page isELIgnored = "false" %>`

at the top of the JSP page to make it evaluable to the appropriate value, instead of rendering plain text.

Comment: thanks alot, looks like adding the library <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> imediately fixed the issue.